# Azure RecoveryServicesBackupClient Restore disks begin_trigger method returns ResourceNotFoundError

Tags: python, azure, sdk, restore

I am attempting to recover an VM disk from backup vault recovery point to a different resource group and storage account.
When using CLI, it works properly. But when using python SDK, I got a ResourceNotFound Error. However, there are no details on the not-found resource exception.

CLI ( result: disk created properly and deleted after to reuse the same recovery point in python):

```
az backup restore restore-disks --vault-name <MASKED VAULT NAME> --item-name "VM;iaasvmcontainerv2;<MASKED RGNAME>;lvmarctest01" --resource-group "<MASKED RGNAME>" --rp-name 933115606147395682 --storage-account stscn0equdevscn --storage-account-resource-group <MASKED TARGET RG> --container-name "IaasVMContainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;<MASKED RGNAME>;lvmarctest01" —target-resource-group <MASKED TARGET RG>
```

Python SDK (failed with stack trace below):

```
trigger_restore_properties = IaasVMRestoreRequest(
    recovery_type = "RestoreDisks",
    restore_with_managed_disks = True,
    recovery_point_id = '/subscriptions/<MASKED SUBSCRIPTION##########>/resourceGroups/<MASKED RGNAME>/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/<MASKED VAULT NAME>/backupFabrics/Azure/protectionContainers/IaasVMContainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;<MASKED RGNAME>;lvmarctest01/protectedItems/VM;iaasvmcontainerv2;<MASKED RGNAME>;lvmarctest01/recoveryPoints/933115606147395682',
    storage_account_id = "/subscriptions/<MASKED SUBSCRIPTION##########>/resourceGroups/<MASKED TARGET RG>/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/stscn0equdevscn",
    target_resource_group_id = "/subscriptions/<MASKED SUBSCRIPTION##########>/resourceGroups/<MASKED TARGET RG>")`
    `trigger_restore_request = RestoreRequestResource(properties=trigger_restore_properties)`
    `poller=rsbc.restores.begin_trigger(
    vault_name = "<MASKED VAULT NAME>",
    resource_group_name = "<MASKED RGNAME>",
    fabric_name = "Azure",
    container_name = "iaasVMContainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;<MASKED RGNAME>;lvmarctest01",
    protected_item_name = "VM;iaasvmcontainerv2;<MASKED RGNAME>;lvmarctest01",
    recovery_point_id = '/subscriptions/<MASKED SUBSCRIPTION##########>/resourceGroups/<MASKED RGNAME>/providers/Microsoft.RecoveryServices/vaults/<MASKED VAULT NAME>/backupFabrics/Azure/protectionContainers/IaasVMContainer;iaasvmcontainerv2;<MASKED RGNAME>;lvmarctest01/protectedItems/VM;iaasvmcontainerv2;<MASKED RGNAME>;lvmarctest01/recoveryPoints/933115606147395682',
    parameters=trigger_restore_request,
    polling = False)
```

Traceback (most recent call last):

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/suibin/Desktop/Projects/DXC/BunkerProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/tracing/decorator.py", line 78, in wrapper_use_tracer
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/suibin/Desktop/Projects/DXC/BunkerProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/mgmt/recoveryservicesbackup/activestamp/operations/_restores_operations.py", line 212, in begin_trigger
    raw_result = self._trigger_initial(
  File "/Users/suibin/Desktop/Projects/DXC/BunkerProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/mgmt/recoveryservicesbackup/activestamp/operations/_restores_operations.py", line 150, in _trigger_initial
    map_error(status_code=response.status_code, response=response, error_map=error_map)
  File "/Users/suibin/Desktop/Projects/DXC/BunkerProject/venv/lib/python3.10/site-packages/azure/core/exceptions.py", line 107, in map_error
    raise error
azure.core.exceptions.ResourceNotFoundError: Operation returned an invalid status 'Not Found
```

expecting python SDK to also create the disks successfully

Comment: too much code, please reduce to this:
https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The python codes are simple, but the arguments pass to the functions are long. Essentially, what I had: 
1. trigger_restore_properties = IaasVMRestoreRequest( args);
2. trigger_restore_request = RestoreRequestResource(args);
3. (trigger the restore) poller=rsbc.restores.begin_trigger( args) -> got exception on ResourceNotFound

Comment: I passed the equivalent of args as in the CLI, which was successful. The ResourceNotFound exception does not provide enough information to further debug  maybe some args were incorrect.